# Sunspot Gem Update Causes Error undefined method `searchable'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

When I use 2.0.0 I have no problems.

When I update to 2.1.1 I get the error.

On my server Amazon Linux
Using Passenger with ruby 2.0.0p451 I receive the undefined method `searchable'

Strange thing is that this works fine on my dev box

OSX 10.9.4
Using the same ruby version.

Any guidance would be very helpful

Thanks
Rod

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself.

I had to manually install the gem using a combination of "sudo gem install sunspot-rails -v 2.1.0" and "gem install sunspot_rails -v 2.1.0"

It appears that it was a rights issue. I figured this out by looking in the gems folder for my Ruby version.

Hopefully this will help someone debug these issues in the future.